# Copy post meta custom field to other custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, custom-fields

How can i copy value from post meta to other filed meta in one post?
for ex:

```
copy value from custom_field_1 (if exist) or custom_field_2 (if exist) to custom_ field_3
```

**Just one of field1 or field2 has a value and field 3 always has e value copied from fiel1 or field2.**

All custom fields are in one post (woo product) meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1) **The old way** from `$product_id` a dynamic product ID *(or the order ID)*:

```
if( ( $value = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_field_1', true ) || $value = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_field_2', true ) ) && ! get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_field_3', true ) ){
    update_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_field_3', $value );
}
```

2) **The new way** *(since [WooCommerce 3, CRUD methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0))* from `$product`, the `WC_Product` Object *(or the from* `$order`*, the* `WC_Order` *Object)*:

```
if( ( $value = $product->get_meta( 'custom_field_1' ) || $value = $product->get_meta( 'custom_field_2') ) && ! $product->get_meta( 'custom_field_3' ) ){
    $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_field_3', $value );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Both ways work.

Comment: thank you very much LoicTheAztec. Just i copy the second code in functions.php or needs a modification?

Comment: Thank you very much LoicTheAztec. Can you give me the complete function works for for all products  of a woocommerce store? thx

Comment: @Mani It depends where you want to display them and how… What are the meta_keys? where exactly you want to display the values? in what html structure they need to be displayed?

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec
Hi. Each order has "delivery_time" OR "time-to_send" meta field. And always one of them has a value. I need a custom function that detects if a "time_to_sent_" field has a value, copy the value to "delivery_time" field at the order custom meta for each woocommerce order.