# Copy WooCommerce sale price meta to a custom field

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to get woocommerce sale price meta field from the plugin woocommerce price based on country and then copy it to another custom field. The code seems to create an error? Am I getting the price in the wrong way?

```
if( ( $value = $product->get_meta( 'canada_sale_price' ) && ! $product->get_meta( 'customfieldprice' ) ){
    $product->update_meta_data( 'customfieldprice', $value );
}
```

I tried also using the native regular and sale price from WooCommerce but no success...

```
if( ( $value = $product->get_price() || $value = $product->get_regular_price() ) ) { update_post_meta( $product_id, 'customfieldprice', $value ); }
```

Comment: Please provide complete code, not just a few lines.

Comment: @VijayHardaha this is my full code actually, It is based from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185806/copy-post-meta-custom-field-to-other-custom-field

Comment: Sorry to inform you, that's not the full code. there will be more code that will allow you to link these lines. Basically, we understand you want to copy the fields data but we don't know on what action it should be copied. Do you want it to copy when you update/create the product in the backend or on any other action? or do you want to perform copy on all the existing products as well as on new products?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy when I update/create the product in the backend. Also, I often use WP all import to modify the prices in bulk. It must make sure to also update the field.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to use `woocommerce_process_product_meta` action and hook your function code with it. For WP All import you can directly map the custom field with your price column.

Comment: I created an error(Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price() on null in /nas/content/live/), here is my code: `add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'add_cad_price_to_acf_custom_field' );

function add_cad_price_to_acf_custom_field() {

if( ( $value = $product->get_price() || $value = $product->get_regular_price() ) ) 
{ 
  update_post_meta( $product_id, 'codisto_product_price_cad', $value ); 
}

}
`

Comment: @VijayHardaha any info ?

Comment: Your code is wrong. I will submit the correct code in answer after a few mins.

Comment: @VijayHardaha any news ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_process_product_meta` action to perform your copy process and can get the sale price from `$_POST` and validate and format it then you can store it in your custom meta key.

**NOTE: I have used `your_custom_field_meta_key` in the example, you can change it to your desired key name.**

```php
/**
 * Copy WooCommerce product sales price to custom meta field.
 * When a product is created or updated in the backend.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function vh_wc_copy_product_sales_price_into_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    // Check & Validate the woocommerce meta nonce.
    if ( ! ( isset( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'] ) || wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'] ), 'woocommerce_save_data' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $sale_price = isset( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) ) : null;

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_custom_field_meta_key', wc_format_decimal( $sale_price ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'vh_wc_copy_product_sales_price_into_custom_field', 99 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it loo like it is not working? I have tried both ways by adding the meta key id and the meta key name. I also tried to use _price  @VijayHardaha

Comment: And how did you test it's not working and where did you add this code? and did you set some values for sale price in the backend and then updated the product?

Comment: I added the code in functions php and yes I have values set for regular and sale price. I just updated the page and nothing is copied in my custom field.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue, you didn't mention that you already have a custom input field on your page. I was assuming you'll use just a meta key and will use somewhere. So if you have a custom input field from a plugin or you added it with custom code then remove it. and if you're using the Custom Field meta box that will override the value and will set empty data, so you'll find this code as not working but it does. it copies the data but your custom input with an empty field overrides the data.

Comment: You can try to use `save_post` action with priority `999` to avoid this conflict, but you'll need to validate the post type before saving anything because `save_post` runs for all the post types so make sure you make a `if` check for `product` post type.

Comment: @ VijayHardaha Like this ? 

function vh_wc_copy_product_sales_price_into_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    // Check & Validate the woocommerce meta nonce.
    if ( get_post_type() === 'ACF_custom_field_name' )  {
        return;
    }

    $sale_price = isset( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) ) : null;

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ACF_custom_field_name', wc_format_decimal( $sale_price ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'vh_wc_copy_product_sales_price_into_custom_field', 999 );

Comment: Any news? Seems my code dosent work. @VijayHardaha

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code with recommendations above and it works well now.

For anyone looking for the solution, here is the code:

```
/**
 * Copy WooCommerce product sales price to custom meta field.
 * When a product is created or updated in the backend.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function vh_wc_copy_product_sales_price_into_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    // Check & Validate the woocommerce meta nonce.
    if ( ! ( isset( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'] ) || wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'] ), 'woocommerce_save_data' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $sale_price = isset( $_POST['_price'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['_price'] ) ) : null;
    
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'codisto_product_price_cad', wc_format_decimal( $sale_price ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'vh_wc_copy_product_sales_price_into_custom_field', 99 );

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_value_on_update_product', 10, 3);

function add_value_on_update_product($post_id, $post, $update){
    if ($post->post_status != 'publish' || $post->post_type != 'product') {
        return;
    }
    
    // Check & Validate the woocommerce meta nonce.
    
    if ( ! ( isset( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'] ) || wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'] ), 'woocommerce_save_data' ) ) ) {
        
        return;
    }

    if (!$product = wc_get_product( $post )) {
        return;
    }
    
    $sale_price = isset( $_POST['_canada_sale_price'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['_canada_sale_price'] ) ) : null; 
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'codisto_product_price_cad', wc_format_decimal( $sale_price ) ); 
   
}
```